# Discord.py fetch a message link

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made a starboard for my discord.py bot and now I want to add a "Jump to Content" line which redirects to the message, here is my current code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member):
    schannel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    
    if (reaction.emoji == '⭐') and (reaction.count >= 3):
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 15105570)
        embed.set_author(name = reaction.message.author.name, icon_url = reaction.message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name = "Message Content", value = reaction.message.content)
        
        if len(reaction.message.attachments) > 0:
            embed.set_image(url = reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
        
        embed.set_footer(text = f" ⭐ {reaction.count} | # {reaction.message.channel.name}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await schannel.send(embed = embed)
```

Please help me with that, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `jump_url` message attribute and put it in as a hyperlink

`[text to click](url)`

Note: hyperlinks won’t work on embed **title**, **footer** or **field names**